# primeNg2.0 bar not show in graph

Tags: angular, primeng

```
this.LineChart = {
            labels: ['7:00', '7:10', '7:20', '7:30', '7:40', '7:50 ',
                     '8:00', '8:10', '8:20', '8:30', '8:40', '8:50' ,
                     '9:00', '9:10', '9:20', '9:30', '9:40', '9:50' ,
                     '10:00', '10:10', '10:20', '10:30', '10:40', '10:50',
                     '11:00', '11:10', '11:20', '11:30', '11:40', '11:50', '12:00'
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Present Person',
                    data: [
                          this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[0] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[1] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[2] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[3] : 0
                        , this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[4] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[5] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[6] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[7] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[8] :0
                        , this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[9] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[10] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[11] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[12] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[13] :0
                        , this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[14] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[15] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[16] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[17] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[18] :0
                        , this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[19] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[20] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[21] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[22] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[23] :0
                        , this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[24] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[25] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[26] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[27] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[28] :0
                        , this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[29] : 0, this.personCountArr != null ? this.personCountArr[30] : 0,
                    ],
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
                    borderColor: "#1E88E5",
                },
            ]
        };
    }
```

Comment: what is the error in console ? any detail about this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probabaly there are two case why your graph is not showing that are either

1. you have not import chartModule in your appModule , so graph is not showing anywhere , if so please follow below steps

   ```
    import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

   imports: [
     ...
     chartModule,
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. or you data provided is invalid